# Excel - Dynamic conditional drop down list

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

is there away I can create a dynamic conditional drop down list with information I already have in a table?

eg.

```
ADI             Account type
HSBC            Day to Day
HSBC            Serious Saver
CBA             Net Saver
CBA             Everyday Savings
```

In another table, when I select the ADI in drop down list in one cell, how can I create a distinct list? In the next column I would like the drop down to show all the Account types for that ADI by looking at the ADI column to determine which Account types should appear eg. maybe using sumproduct formula, without having to create a list in Excel under each ADI?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you make it so that lets say 'Serious Saver' and 'Day to Day' are on the same line corresponding to 'HSBC', and you did this again for the two under CBA then yes.

1. Create first list as usual, data validation, list, Source = First column. Let's say dropdown is in cell A1
2. Highlight your table both columns, go to formula tab, choose 'Create from Selection', ensure only 'Left Column' is ticked, click OK.
3. Create second list by going to data validation, list, but this in time 'SOURCE' type '=INDIRECT(A1)